# webkit's styling for a search input element using right-to-left text

Tags: html, css, webkit, right-to-left

I am using a search input in my markup like so:

```
<input type="search" placeholder="search" />
```

Webkit styles an input element of type 'search' in a number of ways.

One feature is that when you start entering input - you see a cancel ('x') button on the right hand side of the input element.

However, if you are using a right-to-left language such as Hebrew or Arabic - the webkit cancel button still appears on the right hand side (instead of the lhs).

Here is [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/5cgkQ/1/) which demonstrates this point.

1. Is this a webkit bug?
2. If it is a bug - Is there a workaround where I can still use `type="search"` in my markup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s not a bug in the strict sense, since there is no public specification on the cancel button. It’s a (mis)feature, or incomplete localization. It has been reported e.g. as [Bug 51499](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=51499) at WebKit Bugzilla in 2010, and looks like it won’t be fixed.

Comment: after some googling I actually found a workaround for this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness, I just found a **workaround** for this problem on [this post](http://css-tricks.com/webkit-html5-search-inputs/)

The following code will enable you to style and position the 'x' button according to your needs.

```
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button {

   /* Remove default */
    -webkit-appearance: none;

    /* Now your own custom styles */
    ...
    ...
}
```

See a [LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/5cgkQ/3/) of this.

Similarly you could remove the webkit cancel button entirely like this:

```
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button
{
  display: none;
}
```